# Is it possible to disallow access to myapp.herokuapp.com?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'd like to disallow acces to myapp.herokuapp.com, and make the app accesible only through myapp.com. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [rack-canonical-host](https://github.com/tylerhunt/rack-canonical-host). Then, there's a simple one-liner to redirect all requests to `myapp.com`. In your `config.ru` file,

```
use Rack::CanonicalHost, 'myapp.com'
```